# How to replace NULL values with the following NOT NULL value? (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, hana

How can I replace `NULL` values with the following `NOT NULL` value (so the next row with a value in that column that is `NOT NULL`)?

Imagine following table (click on it):

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PePK.png)

```
a    100
b    NULL
c    102
d    NULL
e    NULL
f    104
```

Goal is that a is 100, b, c are 102 and d, e, f are 104.

I use `HANA` as database.

Best regards. Thank you.

Comment: Are we to assume that the alphabetical ordering of the first column is what determines the order of the data?

Comment: @TomH: Thank you for the corrections. Yes, you can assume that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with HANA, but this SQL is pretty generic and ANSI compliant, so it should work with most SQL engines. Some of the simpler engines don't support subqueries, but most should.

```
SELECT
    T1.col1,
    COALESCE(T1.col2, T2.col2) AS col2
FROM
    My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.col1 =
        (
        SELECT MIN(T3.col1)
        FROM My_Table T3
        WHERE
            T3.col1 > T1.col1 AND
            T3.col2 IS NOT NULL
        )
```

The idea of the query is that it `JOIN`s the table to itself to get the next row (the T2 table alias) without a `NULL` value in `col2`.